# django 1.9.5 testing tutorial

Tags: django

I am new to Django 1.9.5, when trying the tutorial part 5 in the official website.

I followed their instructions and coded the tests.py file found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial05/

But when I run it, this is what I got:

```
ImportError: Failed to import test module: polls.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 254, in _find_tests
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 232, in _get_module_from_name__import__(name)

  File "C:\Users\--\Desktop\Django\mysite\polls\tests.py", line 11, in <module>class QuestionMethodTests(TestCase):

  File "C:\Users\--\Desktop\Django\mysite\polls\tests.py", line 20, in QuestionMethodTests

 self.assertEqual(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Can any Django experts help me to understand the why is this happening and how do I solve it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you include `self` in the line `def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question(self):` ? Or maybe you missed that line completely?

Comment: I added the self in the line as i followed their code word for word. But I got this error and I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Did you indent the code correct? It looks like, from the traceback, that you put the line `self.assertEqual(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)` under the class scope, and not in the function scope.

Comment: I am using Notepad++ to code and I use Tab to indent, I am not sure if this information helps.

Comment: Please show your code. Don't use tabs to indent, it's asking for trouble.

Comment: I just found out the problem, when I copied the code from the website directly. Their indents looks exactly the same as what I would have seen if I indent in Notepad++. However, Notepad++ does not recognize it as a valid one. Thank you everybody for helping me!